# VBA Outlook Code for Group By Sender and Then Sort By Number of Emails Sent

Tags: vba, outlook

What VBA script do I need to group Outlook emails by sender and sort by the total number of emails sent by that sender?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook cannot do that - it only sorts or groups on a property set on a message. Number of emails sent by a particular user is not something set on any given message.